# access path url parameter in view in Django

Tags: django

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I have two modesl `course` and `chapter`

I want to pass `course.pk` in `CreateView` of `chapter` since chapter is related to `course`.

This is my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from courses.views import Courses, NewCourse, CourseView, NewChapter

app_name = 'course'
urlpatterns = [
    path('all', Courses.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('new', NewCourse.as_view(), name='new'),
    path('<pk>/detail', CourseView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<course_id>/chapter/add', NewChapter.as_view(), name='new_chapter')
]
```

and `NewChapter(CreateView)`

```
class NewChapter(CreateView):
    template_name = 'courses/chapter/new_chapter.html'
    model = Chapter
    fields = ['name']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewChapter, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        course = Course.objects.get(pk=kwargs['course_id'])
        if course is None:
            messages.error(self.request, 'Course not found')
            return reverse('course:list')

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.course = Course.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['course_id'])
        form.save()
```

I also want to carry on validation if the Course with passed `course_id` exists or not. If it does not exists user will be redirected back otherwise he will be able to add chapter to it.

But it is giving error as

```
KeyError at /course/9080565f-76f4-480a-9446-10f88d1bdc8d/chapter/add

'course_id'
```

**How to access parameters of path url in view?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `self.kwargs`, not `kwargs`.

```
course = Course.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['course_id'])
```

Comment: But, `**kwargs` is passed in `get_context_data()` so, it should work.

Comment: Well, since it didn't work, you should ask why. And the answer is that those are completely different things; the `kwargs` passed to that method are just normal method keyword arguments, nothing at all to do with the arguments captured from the URL.